# Parsing HTML to extract array of DIV content by class

Tags: php, dom, xpath

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://www.wireclub.com/chat/room/music");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = array();

foreach($xpath->evaluate('//div[@class="message clearfix"]/node()') as $childNode) {
$result[] = $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
}
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($result);
```

I would like the content of each individual DIV in an array to be processed individually.

This code is clumping every DIV together.

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve all the div and get the nodeValue

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadHTML($html);

 $myDivs =  $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
 foreach($myDivs as $key => $value) {
      $result[] = $value->nodeValue;
 }

 var_dump($result);
```

for class you should

you could use you code

```
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
 $myElem = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
 foreach($myElem as $key => $value) {
   $result[] = $value->nodeValue;
 }
```

Comment: This is good but it should be $value->nodeValue and it's stripping away the HTML of the DIV contents. I would prefer to keep the HTML intact.

Comment: @JeffGriffiths   yes is  nodeValue ... please update your question and show me the sample of what you get now and the result you need ..